# How can I fix this build time error appearing in Xcode 11.3.1 - Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello guys I'm pretty new to Swift and Xcode. I followed this tutorial https://enlight.nyc/projects/weather-mobile-app/ 
in order to create a simple weatherApp.
but I encountered this error when I tried to build and run my project. I found some solutions here on Stack Overflow, tried all of them and haven't been able to fix this since.

Here is the Github link containing the actual project.

https://github.com/blackfly972/WeatherApp

Thanks in advance for your help.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VsJA.png)

Comment: Post your actual project in github please, so we can try to compile it ourselves. You are not providing enough info to give any other kind of help.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added a Google Drive link containing the project.

Comment: Your project on Google Drive is missing files in the "Cell" and "NetworkManager" folders.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler hum that is weird... I just verified the files are there and are shared...

Comment: Download it yourself and extract it to a separate folder to see for yourself. Those files might not actually be where you think they are. They probably show up in your Xcode project just fine, but they might not actually be in the corresponding folders in your filesystem.

Comment: Please use Github instead of Google Drive. It is impossible to download it the way it is.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler sorry for all this trouble I edited my post and added the GitHub repository. please let me know if something is missing. thank you all again for your help I really appreciate that.

Comment: @ivanmoskalev yes, thank you so much I edited my post with a GitHub link instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have two `ViewController.swift` files in your project. Delete the one that has no code in it (or very little code, rather).

Note that after doing that, you're going to get a ton of errors because you're not importing UIKit in several places that you should be. To fix those, just add:

```
import UIKit
```

to the top of these files:

- ForecastCell.swift
- HourlyCell.swift
- ForecastViewController.swift
- ViewController.swift (the one you didn't delete)
- ImageViewExtension.swift